# how to return a sql query using jwt in php?

Tags: php, jwt

I'm new using jwts and I want to return a query,
how could i do it?
With this code I generate the token with the header, payload etc..

Help would be greatly appreciated

// php code //

```
 $secret = "examamplesecrett";
    
    function CreateToken($secret){
    
    
    $header =  json_encode(
        [
        "type"=> "JWT","alg" => "HS256"
        ]
    
    );
    
    // creas el payload
    $payload =  json_encode(
        [
            'idUsuarioexample' => '100',
            'iat' => time(),
            'exp' => time() + 1800,
       
        ]
    );
    
    
    
    $headerbase64 = str_replace('*','',strtr(base64_encode($header),'*/','-_'));
    
    $payloadbase64 = str_replace('*','',strtr(base64_encode($payload),'*/','-_'));
    
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256',$headerbase64.'.'.$payloadbase64,$secret,true);
    
    $base64signature = str_replace('*','',strtr(base64_encode($signature),'+/','-_'));
    
    $jwt = $headerbase64.".".$payloadbase64.".".$base64signature;
    
    return $jwt;
    } 
    
    $token = CreateTokenToken($secret);
    
    echo $token ;
```

Comment: *I want to return a query* - what does it mean exactly? And how is *returning a query* related to creating a JWT? For me, it's quite unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get all the data from some msql query and put in the payload